# How much is the difference between html parsing and web crawling in python

Tags: python, django, web-crawler

I need to grab some data from websites in my django website.
Now i am confused whether i should use python parsing libraries or web crawling libraries. Does search engine libraries also fall in same category

I want to know how much is the difference between the two and if i want to use those functions  inside my website which should i use

Comment: What web crawling libraries you have for Python?

Comment: i tried Scrapy and was not happy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can get away with background web crawling use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). If need to immediately grab something use [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) (more robust) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) (faster). If you are going to be doing the later, use the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library. I would avoid using BeautifulSoup, mechanize, urllib2, httplib.

Comment: What's wrong with BeautifulSoup, mechanize, urllib2 and httplib ? Speed, error tolerance? Just for knowledge.

Comment: @Mandx BeautifulSoup is very long in the tooth, has not been actively developed for some time, the author has expressed a lack of interest in continuing development. html5lib/lxml are better choices today. Mechanize is poorly documented, and I've generally seen people more confused by it than anything else. Scrapy on the other hand is extremely well documented, and has a nice API. Requests is a much more pythonic, easier to use, less hair-pulling http library than the alternative. But hey, don't take my word for it, check 'em all out!

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely use Requests, the [difference](https://gist.github.com/973705) make it almost mandatory. Also, I think I can add [PyQuery](https://bitbucket.org/olauzanne/pyquery) to extract info from HTML/XML data. Using the same selector syntax as of jQuery for selecting nodes, it returns lxml nodes based on the query. Very handy indeed.

Answer (score 1):

HTML parse will parse the page and you can collect the links present in it. These links you can add to queue and visit these pages. Combine these steps in a loop and you made a basic crawler.

Crawling libraries are the ready to use solutions which do the crawling. They provide more features like detection of recursive links, cycles etc. A lot of features you would want to code would have already been done within these libraries.

However first option is preferred if you have some special requirements which libraries do not satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar things previously. Web-crawlers were not usefull to me if I wanted the parsing to be done immediately in order to fetch something and be presented to the user. For batch-job stuff they're more appropriate. I found [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [lxml](http://lxml.de) and [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to be quite usefull.