# How can i grab the hyperlinks in web page using python

Tags: python, html-parsing, urllib2, lxml

I have web page in which i have the structure like

```
<div>
<ul>
<li class=tree>
<a>  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

NOw i want to grab all those hyperlinks and put in text file in python

Comment: Did you try one of the **Related** links?

Comment: this link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times. Go find Beautiful Soup and read the docs.

Comment: @Ignacio I don't want to use beautiful Soup .Someone was saying that beautiful soap is not currently being developed.  Is there any other alternative

Comment: @bidu any reliable source saying that `BeautifulSoup` is not currently being developed (Update: their [launchpad site](https://code.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup) does not appear inactive to me)?

Comment: @Onesimus see the comment of zeekay in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236794/how-much-is-the-difference-between-html-parsing-and-web-crawling-in-python . Actually i am beginning python parsing so i don't to spend time on something which is not actively ddeveloped and i have to switch to something else later in stage

Comment: @bidu see my update in the previous comment. Anyway, thanks for the link and I got interested in `scrapy`. I'll check it out :-)

Comment: @Onesimus This link here also mentiones about BS problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922032/parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup-which-of-these-is-better-for-what

Comment: @bidu it's the problem with the 3.1.x series and the 3.2.x is the recommended, working version.

Comment: If you want to avoid BeautifulSoup either use lxml or scrapy.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module `xml.dom.minidom`, though it is not ported to certain versions of python3 if that is an issue.